# How can I get the text from a table in HTML?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S10_FNCS_Week5_NAE. Specifically, I am trying to get the placement and number of points earned by a specific player. I went to the website and found the instance where the specific player ("Nickmercs") was located in the HTML which looked like this: 
[HTML Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVfLJ.png)
You can see the "rank" is shown above his name as 56, and the points are shown a few lines below his name which is also 56. I then wrote the following Python 3 program to scrape the data from the website:

```
import requests

class tracker:

url = "https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S10_FNCS_Week5_NAE"

    def getReq(website):
        req = requests.get(website)
        if req:
            return req 

    req = getReq(url)
    text = req.text
    index = text.find("nickmercs")
    split = text[index:index+1000]
    print (split)
```

Running the program resulted in a large portion of the HTML code, but the instance of "Nickmercs" that it found was not the one I was looking for. The one shown in the picture of the HTML code shown above was the actual first instance if the "Nickmercs" string on the page, but for some reason it was not in the req.text / the response for my request. As a result I went back and modified my code to print out where the first instance actually was, and found that the line was different from what was shown in the HTML code picture. The line that was supposed to list the names "Nate Hill, Nickmercs, SypherPK" actually looked like this:

```
<span :style="{ 'color': '#' + metadata.primary_color }">{{ getPlayerNameList(entry.teamAccountIds, 4) }}</span>
```

I have little knowledge of how HTML works, so I am wondering if it is possible to fix this problem. It seems to be calling some (what I imagine is a) method called getPlayerNameList() which places the names in the correct spot, but makes it so I can't easily search the names / scrape the data. Is there a way to get around this? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The site is dynamic, thus, you need some way to access the data populated after the page originally loads. One such way is to use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S10_FNCS_Week5_NAE')
h, *r = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('th' if b.td is None else 'td')] for b in soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'id':'leaderboard'}).table.find_all('tr')]
new_data = {tuple(b.split(', ')):dict(zip([h[0], *h[2:]], [a[1:-1], *c])) for a, b, *c in r}
```

Now, to look up a player by name:

```
data = [b for a, b in new_data.items() if 'Nickmercs' in a][0]
```

Output:

```
{'Rank': '56', 'Points': '56 Top 0.373%', 'Matches': '10', 'Wins': '0', 'K/D': '3.50', 'Avg Place': '16.10'}
```

For your specific target value (Rank):

```
rank = [b for a, b in new_data.items() if 'Nickmercs' in a][0]['Rank']
```

Output:

```
56
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is dynamically loaded from script tags so content is present in response. You can regex out the leaderboard/session info and the accounts info and connect the two via account_id. You find the right account_id based on the player name of interest

```
import requests, re, json

def get_json(pattern):
    p = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
    return p.findall(r.text)[0]

r = requests.get('https://fortnitetracker.com/events/epicgames_S10_FNCS_Week5_NAE')
player = 'Nickmercs'
session_info = json.loads(get_json('imp_leaderboard = (.*?);'))
player_info = json.loads(get_json('imp_accounts = (.*?);'))
account_id = [i['accountId'] for i in player_info if i['playerName'] == player][0]
team_info = [i for i in session_info['entries'] if account_id in i['teamId']]
print(team_info)
```

This gives you all the relevant info. Part of that is shown here:

[image]

Specific items:

```
print(team_info[0]['pointsEarned'])
print(team_info[0]['rank'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You are **scraping** the HTML along the javascript code and it is not rendered.

For this task you could use computer vision to extract the table from the page.
Otherwise you can use PhantomJS  (https://phantomjs.org/) to **scrape** the table without using images as it gives you the rendered page.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish, as does 'to scrap'.